# K Fold Cross Validation, Variable Selection in LDA

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, feature-selection

I'm currently working on a multi-class classification problem and I attempt to use `lda` for the same. I have 2 questions here.

1) Is it possible to perform k-fold cross validation in `lda` I have noticed that we can perform leave one out cross validation in `lda`. But how to perform k-fold cross validation (k > 1)?

2) Is it possible to perform a variable selection in `lda` ? I did google for this quite a bit but, I'm not able to find an answer for the same.

The main aim here is that, I'm looking at a survey data and I aim to fit a model and look at the variables which best correlate with the response variable.

Comment: Do you mean lda in R, or lda in general?

Comment: Hi, I meant lda in R